# Mongoose populate single element of array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, populate

Is there a simple way to only populate a single element of an array of object ids stored in a mongoose document?

**The problem**

Let's assume the following Schema

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true},
    posts: [{type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Posts'}],
})
```

Now if I want to populate the first post of a specific user I would try this:

```
doc.populate('posts.0');
```

Mongoose does not throw any kind of error but does not populate the first post.

I don't understand this behavior, because with this schema

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true},
    posts: [{postRef: { type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Posts' }}],
})
```

and this command

```
doc.populate('posts.0.postRef');
```

everything turns out as expected.

**My use case**

In my case every user can only access some fields of some of the posts stored in the database. So my idea was to iterate over every post id and select the accessible fields to populate for.
My current code looks like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < doc.posts.length; i++) {
  const postId = doc.posts[i];
  if (user.canAccessPost(postId) {
    const fields = user.getFieldsForPost(postId);
    await doc.populate({
      path: `posts.${i}`,
      select: fields,
    })
  }
}
```

My mongoose version is **6.1**.

Is there any way to populate just one array element or should I start looking for another solution to achieve this?